# Android WebView doesn't finish

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview that I try to kill, but it is a hard bastard! I've tried:

in my activity:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {

    if (webView_ != null) {
        webView_.finish(getApplicationContext());
        webView_.destroy();
        webView_ = null;
    }
    super.onStop();
}
```

and in my webview:

```
public void finish(Context context) {

    stopLoading();
    pauseTimers();
    if (alarm_ != null)
        alarm_.cancelAlarm(context);
    if (webViewErrorHandler_ != null)
        webViewErrorHandler_.removeCallbacks(reloadRunnable_);
    if (requestQueue_ != null) {
        requestQueue_.clear();
        requestQueue_ = null;
    }
    callHiddenWebViewMethod("onPause");
}

private void callHiddenWebViewMethod(String name){
    if( this != null ){
        try {
            Method method = WebView.class.getMethod(name);
            method.invoke(this);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            Log.e("MYWEBVIEW", "No such method: " + name);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e("MYWEBVIEW", "Illegal Access: " + name);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            Log.e("MYWEBVIEW", "Invocation Target Exception: " + name);
        }
    }
}
```

but when I look at it in debugger there are still threads of this webview running!

And you have to know that I especially want it to work after onPause ;)

Answer (score 1):

The activity's onStop is not guaranteed to be called. Here is a portion of doc that reads:

> The column labeled "Killable after?" indicates whether or not the
>   system can kill the process hosting the activity at any time after the
>   method returns, without executing another line of the activity's code.
>   Three methods are marked "yes": (onPause(), onStop(), and
>   onDestroy()). Because onPause() is the first of the three, once the
>   activity is created, onPause() is the last method that's guaranteed to
>   be called before the process can be killed—if the system must recover
>   memory in an emergency, then onStop() and onDestroy() might not be
>   called. Therefore, you should use onPause() to write crucial
>   persistent data (such as user edits) to storage. However, you should
>   be selective about what information must be retained during onPause(),
>   because any blocking procedures in this method block the transition to
>   the next activity and slow the user experience.

Check http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html

Try moving the code inside onStop to onPause method.

Please post you findings.

Comment: onStop is called - I've checked this. And I wrote that I do not want to pauseTimers in onPause. I want my webview to work in the background. I parse sites while webview is not visible.